# How to load user control with scroll bars in WPF?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am trying to load a `UserControl` in the `Window` by using content control's content property in code behind. Every thing is fine, but my friends were not able to see all the control on the page due to resolution problem. How can I fix this to have scroll bar. I have tried putting `ScrollViewer` also, but it's not working. So, my solution works on the bigger `Window` which developed, but its not working on the Smaller resolution windows.

Sample code structure of loading the `UserControl`:

`Window.Xaml`

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <ContentControl Name="ContentX" Margin="15,10,15,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">      
        <Label FontWeight="Black" FontSize="18" FontFamily="Calibri">Some Content</Label>      
    </ContentControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

`Window.Xaml.cs`

```
 ContentX.Content = new UserControl();

 UserControl.Xaml
 //Contains the Code for User Control
```

Comment: Post some code please, of the last thing you tried.

Comment: Hi Naxto please see my sample codeb

Comment: In what way is the scroll viewer solution not working?

Comment: when the screen resolution is smaller , i am not able to see any Vertical Scroll bars

Comment: The scroll viewer - is it the first element in the window or is it resides in a panel (like `StackPanel`)?

Comment: Yes, Scrollviewer resides in Some Other Panel

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved my Content Control is in another Grid Column where i fixed the width and height to be *, now i removed it it's working fine when i place it inside a Scroll Viewer